# Enchant M60 in Magicka?

Tags: magicka

I have just gotten the M60 in Magicka, and it's neat, but when I enchant and shoot it acts just like a sword?  Can I not use magick bullets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The M60 acts as a melee weapon when enchanted, and will slash through your enemies. The disadvantage to this is that you cannot store an enchant and have the benefit of using a ranged weapon.

Comment: It's worth noting that all weapons behave the exact same way when using an enchantmented attack, regardless of their characteristics.